# JavaScript Number changes while scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently working on a website. I want to have a fixed text (I know how to do that) that changes if you scroll.

So if you're on top of the page it shows '0' and then, while scrolling, the number goes up and up and when you scrolled one viewport-height it should be '10000'.

I think this should be done with javascript, but I'm just a beginner with it. Could you please help me? Thank you very much.

**edit**

Thanks Ajay for the tip with the onscroll function. But [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onscroll) always just adds a number on scrolling. I want something like [this](http://www.onemilescroll.com/) (look at the top left hand corner). Where the size is relative to the position on the site and not the scrolling wheel.

Comment: show us the code? anything?

Comment: Please read the [help] to see how to ask. We need a [mcve]

Comment: Please do some research on "scroll update JavaScript viewport"

Comment: Added an example. Please have a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the onScroll event of javascript.

[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onscroll.asp) is a useful link to learn.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not exactly what I looked for. Have a look at my example that I added.

Comment: Okay. Then you can use the jQuery method $(window).scrollTop(). You can multiply it with some constant if you want.
Here is an example. 
$(window).scroll(function (event) {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    // Do something
});